# How can I give a very stripped down login for viewing logs?

Tags: permissions, remote

I have various log files in folders on an RHEL 5 system:

```
/var/log/syslog-ng/A/
/var/log/syslog-ng/B/
/var/log/syslog-ng/C/
```

I would like to be able to give certain users the rights to view/tail (but not modify/delete) all files inside the folders `B` and `C` (and subdirectories) but not to view the contents of folder `A` nor the `/var/log/syslog-ng` folder itself.

What I can imagine is a cut down shell with the only commands being `tail`, `cd`, `grep` and `vi`, with `cd` only able to navigate into the `B` and `C` folders.

A single user/password shared between the people who would be using this information is fine.

How would you recommend achieving this? Is it even possible?

(we currently achieve this with a bash script made available through Apache HTTPD, with the Apache configuration requiring a password if the path being navigated passes above the B or C folders. The script is clunky and hacky to say the least, and doesn't provide any form of live updating apart from a meta-refresh on the generated HTML page - making use of ssh and tail would be a much better user experience, and be less prone to errors)

Comment: i would probably end up writing a webapp for that, you can get good results with javascript; anyway, did you think of creating stripped down logins to a home directory containing hard links of the required logs?

Comment: It had not occurred to me to create hard links, but that would be quite a job - syslog creates the folders for us automatically, and our configuration will have a folder containing the server logs for each server, and another folder for each application running on each server, so you're getting to a lot of links; the folder structure is nice and hierarchical, though, so is easily managed despite the number of files. As for a proper web app, I agree, a web app would do the trick better than our hacky bash script, but 'real' programming isn't an option due to office politics :)

Answer (score 1):

The [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) shell enters a
[restricted mode](http://www.wlug.org.nz/rbash%281%29) (when called
`rbash`) that prevents users -among other things- from altering `PATH`
or changing current directory with `cd`; by coupling this with the
access control restriction provided by UNIX groups, you can restrict
users to view only files in a certain directory.

I would implement it this way:

- Create groups `A`, `B`, etc. - each group can read (but not *write*)
  the the corresponding directory and the log files in it:

  ```
  $ ls -lF /var/log/syslog-ng
  drwxr-x--- root A  ...  A/
  drwxr-x--- root B  ...  B/
  [...]

  $ ls -l /var/log/syslog-ng/A/
  -rwxr----- root A  ...  logfile.log
  -rwxr----- root A  ...  logfile.log.1
  [...]
  ```
- Modify `/etc/group` and add users to these groups according to the
  logs you want them to read:

  ```
  $ tail /etc/group
  [...]
  A: foo
  B: bar
  ```
- Create a directory to host the commands you want to give access to
  the log viewers; let's assume it's `/usr/local/restricted/bin`.
  Copy or hard-link the relevant commands to this directory.
- Modify `/etc/profile` so that you set up the correct `PATH` for the
  restricted users: the restricted PATH should only include
  `/usr/local/restricted/bin` (or any other directory that hosts
  "safe" restricted commands).
- Modify `/etc/passwd` and make sure the users are given the login
  shell `rbash` and the relevant `/var/log/syslog-ng/XXX` directory as
  home.  They can now log in but are jailed to the home directory and
  can only use commands on the restricted PATH.

*Note:* It's easy to circumvent the restricted mode shell if you
provide access to commands that allow users to
[exec](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) an arbitrary command, e.g.,
PERL or almost any editor.

Answer (score 0):

You could export `/var/log/syslog-ng/B` and `/var/log/syslog-ng/C` via a network protocol such as NFS or Samba.

You can create a user with an scp-only shell such as [scponly](http://sublimation.org/scponly/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/). Set that user's home directory to `/home/log-viewers-BC`. Use [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/) to create a view of `/var/log/syslog-ng/B` as `/home/log-viewers-BC/B` and a view of `/var/log/syslog-ng/C` as `/home/log-viewers-BC/C`.

But a `.htaccess` approach is also a good choice, so do investigate in a better set of cgi scripts for live updates.